# Sloq SQL execution (calling store procedures) on huge site

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

First of all, I realize that my question MAY be broad, please bear with me as I've been thinking on how to form it for a month and I still am not 100% sure how to express my issues.

I'm currently developing a website, that will be used by many thousands of users daily. The bottle neck is the communication with the Data Base.

Each and every conversation with the tables is done through stored procedures, whose calls look like this:

```
    public void storedProcedure(int id, out DataSet ds)
{
    ds = new DataSet("resource");

    SqlDataReader objReader = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcedure", DbConn.objConn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

    openConnection(cmd);

    SqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

    objDataAdapter.Fill(ds);

    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

Or

```
   public void anotherStoredProcedure(int var1, int var2, int var3, int var4, string var5,  out DataSet ds)
{
    ds = new DataSet("ai");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("anotherStoredProcedure", DbConn.objConn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@var1", var1));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@var2", var2));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@var3", var3));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@var4", var4));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@var5", var5));

    openConnection(cmd);


    SqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    objDataAdapter.Fill(ds);

    cmd.Connection.Close();

}
```

My objConn is defined as following:

```
    public static string DatabaseConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["objConnLocal"].ConnectionString;
public static SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString);
```

And ofcourse in web.config I have

```
<add name="objConnLocal" connectionString="Initial Catalog=t1;Data Source=1.2.3.4;Uid=id;pwd=pwd;Min Pool Size=20;Max Pool Size=200;" providerName="SQLOLEDB.1"/>
```

Now the issue is: On every page_load there a few sp calls (above), and when the user starts navigating through the page, more calls are made.

At the moment only the developing and testing team are on the site and at times the speed is really slow. Frequently it would keep loading till it times out (err 504).

Another problem (only ever now and then, but certainly frequent enough to be noticeable) on first user login is it would keep trying to run a call but the connection would claim to be opened, even though it shouldn't be. A fairly not-working work-around is

```
private void openConnection(SqlCommand cmd){

    if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }

    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
    try
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

Which makes connecting slow but at least doesn't show the YSOD.

So, what am I doing wrong on my SQL calls so that it is so slow for only 5-10 users? What I have so far:
I've read on Stack Overflow that using "using" is quite nice, but am not entirely sure why and how come as it was a single line comment under an answer. Another idea for improvement was to use several connection strings and not only one.

Resolved:

Changing the wait the connection is established in the connection string from username/pwd to Integrated Security resolved the issue. IF anyone's having similar issue refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17768/ADO-NET-Connection-Pooling-at-a-Glance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - it's a broad question!

For context - many "thousands of users daily" isn't huge from a performance point of view. A well-built ASP.Net application can typically support hundreds of concurrent users on a decently specified developer laptop; assuming 10K users per day, you probably only have a few dozen concurrent users at peak times (of course this depends entirely on the application domain).

The first thing to do is to use a profiler on your running code to see where the performance bottleneck is. This is [available in VS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d.aspx), and there are several 3rd party solutions (I like RedGate and JetBrains).

The profiler will tell you where your code is slow - it should be pretty obvious if it's taking seconds for pages to render.

At first glance, it looks like you have a problem with the database. So you can also use the [SQLServer activity monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212951.aspx) to look at long-running queries.

Comment: I'll read up on the profilers to set it up thanks. And the activity monitors might be great help as well!

Comment: I was finally able to find the issue. We had a procedure that was ruining for quite a while 15-25s and the web-site was timing out, waiting for it. Now the main issue was we used user_id ans password in the connection string, to connect to the DB, thus having 200 connections in total, for all users. If we didn't have this long running SQL this would hardly be a problem. But since we do, we introduced Integrated Security - having a new connection pool for every user, ever since all the problems from above dissipated.

Comment: You still talk about tiny amounts of users. 20 connections - whoooha. Seriously. Fix the broken stored procedure. It should not take 15-25 seconds - somehow me thinks the database programmer was making beginner mistakes. Missing indices, non sargeable sql, stuff like that. FIX THAT.

Answer (score 2):

> Now the issue is: On every page_load there a few sp calls (above), and
>   when the user starts navigating trough the page, more calls are made.

This sounds like you've written webpages which won't display anything until the Stored Procedure calls have completed.  This is never a good idea.

Shift these SP calls into a background thread, so the user at least sees something when they go onto the webpage (like a "Please wait" message).  This can also help prevent timeout messages.

One other thing: you don't say *why* your SPs take so long to run.

If you're dealing with lots of records, its worth running a SQL script (described on the link below) to check for missing SQL Server indexes.

[Finding missing indexes](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/SQLServer/FindingMissingIndexes.htm)

This script shows the missing indexes which have made the most impact to your users, also tells you the syntax of the CREATE INDEX command you'd need to run to add those indexes.